# Google Apps Script trigger function when entered the same value

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

My goal is to catch cell old value independently from new value user entered to cell. A special case is when the user entered exactly the same value to the cell. I want to do some calculations in the same cell, which will depend on the previous value.

For example:

- Old cell value is 3
- User entered that cell, replaced the value to 3 again, and hit enter
- After that, in that cell, I want to set a new value 6 (newValue = oldValue * 2)

I've searched and tried many approaches so far, but none have succeeded. I tried to use `onEdit(e)` and `onChange(e)` triggers, but these failed too. `onEdit(e)` does not trigger when entered the same value. `onChange(e)` cannot operate on value and oldValue as in `onEdit(e)`. Is it possible to fire some code when entered the same value to a cell?

Sample code:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
   var range = e.range;
   var oldValue;
   var newValue;
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
   var editRange = { // do only in range: A2:D4
     top : 2,
     bottom : 4,
     left : 1,
     right : 4
   };

   // exit if active cell is out of range
   var thisRow = range.getRow();
   if (thisRow < editRange.top || thisRow > editRange.bottom) return;
   var thisCol = range.getColumn();
   if (thisCol < editRange.left || thisCol > editRange.right) return;

   // active cell is in range
   newValue = e.value;
   oldValue = e.oldValue;
   if(!e.value) {
     activeCell.setValue(Number(oldValue));
   }
   else {
     if (!e.oldValue) {
       activeCell.setValue(Number(newValue));
     }
     else {
       activeCell.setValue(Number(oldValue) + Number(newValue));
     }
   }
}
```